# Spring-boot jpa how to find entity with max value

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, linked-tables

Lets tell I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE user (ID int AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (ID));
CREATE TABLE points (ID int AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id int, points int,PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

How can I use spring-boot jpa to request user and max points like this?

```
select u.ID,max(p.points) from user u, points p where u.id=p.user_id
```

Or any alternatives to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: Yes, you can use spring data jpa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually create a class to hold result such as

```
public class Result {

private User user;
private int votes;
// getters and setters 
}
```

And write a custom query in the repository to fetch the data

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.package.Result (u, MAX (p.points) ) 
FROM user u
JOIN points p
ON u.id = p.user_id 
GROUP BY u")
List<Result> getPointsPerUser();
```

Replace com.package.Result with appropriate path to the Result class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I need some other information for points record? For example if I need maximum points and when user got that points?

Comment: If you need more columns from `points` table, you can fetch the `points` object rather than using aggregate function. You can replace the select with `u, p` and remove the `GROUP BY` clause. Also modify the `Result` class to accept `points`. This way you have the all the data in the both the table. The drawback is you now have to find the maximum from the `List`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a `Repository` of `User`:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private List<Point> points;
    ...
}
```

With a relationship to the `Points` object:

```
public class Point {
    private int id;
    private User User;
    private int points;
    ...
}
```

I haven't tested, but you should be able to do:

```
User findFirstByIdOrderByPointPointsDesc(int userId)
```

Similar to [example 18 in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).

The only problem you have, regardless of the query or Spring Data, is if you have two users with the same point values. If you need more logic around tie-breaking, it might be more worth it to write a `@Query` (with your query, plus the extra tie-breaking logic) or a `@NativeQuery`.

Answer (score 3):

Below method can be written in Repo and used as Transaction as in dao layer, which will be accessible from service layer.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(transactionId), 0) FROM TransactionPayloadInfo")
int getMaxTransactionId();
```

Comment: This will not work if the table doesn't have any rows.

Answer (score 0):

create a model of data.

```
public class Data {
 private int id;
  private int maxPoints;
 // getters and setters method  
 }
```

And write your query like this for getting model of Data.

```
 @Query(select packagename.Data(u.ID,max(p.points) ) from user u, points p where   u.id=p.user_id)
 Data findUserWithMaxVots();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if I need some other information for points record? For example if I need maximum points and when user got that points?